# ESP32 crashes and doesn't restart with watchdog

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide, esp32

First of all, I'm aware that the code is broken, that isn't the point. It was meant to be broken.

We have 3 pycoms (LoPy4, a LoRa/Sigfox ESP32 based development board, normally runs python but we switched to arduino) in a POC. For some reason (I assume multicore-multithreading pitfalls) sometimes the ESP crashes, and although a watchdog was implemented it doesn't come back online.

So I tried to replicate a crash like that locally which is basically what this sketch does:

```
#include "esp_system.h"
#include "esp_int_wdt.h"
#include "esp_task_wdt.h"

//hw_timer_t *timer = NULL;
//void IRAM_ATTR resetModule(){
//    ets_printf("reboot\n");
//    esp_restart();
//}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  esp_int_wdt_init();
  esp_task_wdt_init(5000, true);
  enableLoopWDT();

//  enableCore0WDT();
//  enableCore1WDT();
  //esp_task_wdt_feed();
//

//  esp_int_wdt_init();

//  timer = timerBegin(0, 80, true); //timer 0, div 80
//  timerAttachInterrupt(timer, &resetModule, true);
//  timerAlarmWrite(timer, 3000000, false); //set time in us
//  timerAlarmEnable(timer); //enable interrupt
}


void loop() {
  delay(500);

  pinMode(6, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(7, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(8, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(10, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(11, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(6, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(7, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(8, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(10, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(11, HIGH);


  while(true) {
    Serial.print("broken");
  }

}
```

As said, I'm not looking for ways to fix this code, which would be easy, commenting the pinmode/writes of the flash-SPI port. I'm just looking for a failsafe way to implement the watchdog that whatever happens, the pycom/ESP will reset.

As you can see in the code, I've tried a few methods, yet, still no luck.

This is what I get as output at the moment

```
ets Jun  8 2016 00:22:57

rst:0x1 (POWERON_RESET),boot:0x12 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:1
load:0x3fff0018,len:4
load:0x3fff001c,len:1100
load:0x40078000,len:9232
load:0x40080400,len:6400
entry 0x400806a8
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (LoadProhibited). Exception was unhandled.
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (IllegalInstruction). Exception was unhandled.
Memory dump at 0x400e8c64: 00000000 00000000 00000000
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (IllegalInstruction). Exception was unhandled.
Memory dump at 0x400e8c64: 00000000 00000000 00000000
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (IllegalInstruction). Exception was unhandled.
Memory dump at 0x400e8c64: 00000000 00000000 00000000
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (IllegalInstruction). Exception was unhandled.
Memory dump at 0x400e8c64: 00000000 00000000 00000000
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (IllegalInstruction). Exception was unhandled.
Memory dump at 0x400e8c64: 00000000 00000000 00000000
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (IllegalInstruction). Exception was unhandled.
Memory dump at 0x400e8c64: 00000000 00000000 00000000
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (IllegalInstruction). Exception was unhandled.
Memory dump at 0x400e8c64: 00000000 00000000 00000000
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (IllegalInstruction). Exception was unhandled.
Memory dump at 0x400e8c64: 00000000 00000000 00000000
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (IllegalInstruction). Exception was unhandled.
Memory dump at 0x400e8c64: 00000000 00000000 00000000
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (IllegalInstruction). Exception was unhandled.
Memory dump at 0x400e8c64: 00000000 00000000 00000000
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (IllegalInstruction). Exception was unhandled.
Memory dump at 0x400e8c64: 00000000 00000000 00000000
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (IllegalInstruction). Exception was unhandled.
Memory dump at 0x400e8c64: 00000000 00000000 00000000
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (IllegalInstruction). Exception was unhandled.
Memory dump at 0x400e8c64: 00000000 00000000 00000000
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (IllegalInstruction). Exception was unhandled.
Memory dump at 0x400e8c64: 00000000 00000000 00000000
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (IllegalInstruction). Exception was unhandled.
Memory dump at 0x400e8c64: 00000000 00000000 00000000
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (IllegalInstruction). Exception was unhandled.
Memory dump at 0x400e8c64: 00000000 00000000 00000000
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (IllegalInstruction). Exception was unhandled.
Memory dump at 0x400e8c64: 00000000 00000000 00000000
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (IllegalInstruction). Exception was unhandled.
Memory dump at 0x400e8c64: 00000000 00000000 00000000
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (IllegalInstruction). Exception was unhandled.
Memory dump at 0x400e8c64: 00000000 00000000 00000000
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (IllegalInstruction). Exception was unhandled.
Memory dump at 0x400e8c64: 00000000 00000000 00000000
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (IllegalInstruction). Exception was unhandled.
Memory dump at 0x400e8c64: 00000000 00000000 00000000
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (IllegalInstruction). Exception was unhandled.
Memory dump at 0x400e8c64: 00000000 00000000 00000000
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (IllegalInstruction). Exception was unhandled.
Memory dump at 0x400e8c64: 00000000 00000000 00000000
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (IllegalInstruction). Exception was unhandled.
Memory dump at 0x400e8c64: 00000000 00000000 00000000
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (IllegalInstruction). Exception was unhandled.
Memory dump at 0x400e8c64: 00000000 00000000 00000000
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (IllegalInstruction). Exception was unhandled.
Memory dump at 0x400e8c64: 00000000 00000000 00000000
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (Unhandled debug exception)
Debug exception reason: Stack canary watchpoint triggered (loopTask) 
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (Interrupt wdt timeout on CPU1)
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (Interrupt wdt timeout on CPU1)
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (Interrupt wdt timeout on CPU1)
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (Interrupt wdt timeout on CPU1)
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (Interrupt wdt timeout on CPU1)
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (Interrupt wdt timeout on CPU1)
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (Interrupt wdt timeout on CPU1)
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (Interrupt wdt timeout on CPU1)
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (Interrupt wdt timeout on CPU1)
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (Interrupt wdt timeout on CPU1)
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (Interrupt wdt timeout on CPU1)
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (Interrupt wdt timeout on CPU1)
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (Interrupt wdt timeout on CPU1)
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (Interrupt wdt timeout on CPU1)
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (Interrupt wdt timeout on CPU1)
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (
```

After this it's complete radio silence...

Comment: What framework are you using? ESP-IDF? Or Arduino? If you want to mix, you can [use Arduino as an ESP-IDF component](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/docs/esp-idf_component.md)

Comment: Arduino, the problem is also that the ESP's are a 2 hour drive away.. So we'd rather do OTA updates.. And I'm not sure if that's possible with the ESP-IDF, and I have no idea if that would magically fix the watchdog problem..

Comment: Did you consult [ESP doc](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/api-reference/system/wdts.html) ? Because if I am not mistaken you have to handle the panic error. Basically you have to make sure that the right CONFIG_ESP32_PANIC is set. But nonetheless if a panic occurs undefined behavior can actually lead to any side effect. Any chance to catch the error in our original code before an actual panic occurs?

Comment: I have the same issue. Any update?

Comment: Not really. We managed to type around the issue for now during the POC. In the actual implementation we will probably go with the ESP-IDF barebone. It seems in ESP-IDF it doesn't have the same behaviour. In what setup/code do you have the problem?